# Lowpass Butterworth filter in Matlab without 'butter' function

Tags: matlab, math, filter

I want to design a lowpass Butterworth filter with mathematics, not with `butter` function.

```
ap=-1.5db
as=-30db
wp=9000
ws=12000
```

Design lowpass Butterworth filter in Matlab with mathematics. Don't use `butter` function.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Digital or analog? Do you need to obtain the transfer function or the impulse response?

Comment: analog filter. i need matlab codes response of the butterworth filter designed

Answer (score 0):

I assume you cannot use `buttap` either. Anyway, you can take a look at those functions by typing `open butapp` or `open butter`. That will give you some ideas.